# Request for simple modeshape 3.x/infinispan SQL DB configuration

Tags: configuration, infinispan, modeshape

I've been trying to get modeshape 3.2 working with a MySQL database and I'm not getting very far. By default everything is in memory which is useless to me.

From what I've pieced together so far it appears I need to configure infinispan to persist the JCR. I've tried adapting various examples I've googled but to no avail.

This is a request for a working/proven configuration as opposed to trying to fix one of the broken configs on the jboss.org site.

Comment: Note, as of infinispan 5.2.5.final theres a bug, you can't declaratively set simpleConnection.connectionUrl. Jira raised.

Answer (score 1):

As of Modeshape 3.2 you can't use infinispan xml config with simpleConnection due to a bug. But here's how you can do it programmatically...

Modeshape config

```
{
    "name" : "My Repository",
    "jndiName" : "",
    "monitoring" : {
        "enabled" : true
    },
    "workspaces" : {
        "default" : "defaultWorkspace",
        "allowCreation" : true
    },
    "storage" : {
        "cacheName" : "myCache",
        "binaryStorage" : {
            "type" : "database",
            "driverClass" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
            "username" : "modeshape",
            "password" : "modeshape",
            "url" : "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/modeshape?autoReconnect=true"
        }
    },
    "security" : {
        "anonymous" : {
            "roles" : ["readonly","readwrite","admin"],
            "username" : "admin",
            "useOnFailedLogin" : true
        },
        "providers" : []
    },
}
```

Then in your code configure and include infinispan like this...

```
ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        Configuration cacheConfig =
        builder
            .transaction()
                .transactionManagerLookup(new GenericTransactionManagerLookup())
                .transactionMode(TransactionMode.TRANSACTIONAL)
                .lockingMode(LockingMode.OPTIMISTIC)
            .loaders()
                .addLoader(JdbcStringBasedCacheStoreConfigurationBuilder.class)
                .fetchPersistentState(false)
                .ignoreModifications(false)
                .purgeOnStartup(false)
                .table()
                    .dropOnExit(false)
                    .createOnStart(true)
                    .tableNamePrefix("ISPN_STRING_TABLE")
                    .idColumnName("ID_COLUMN").idColumnType("VARCHAR(255)")
                    .dataColumnName("DATA_COLUMN").dataColumnType("BLOB")
                    .timestampColumnName("TIMESTAMP_COLUMN").timestampColumnType("BIGINT")
                .simpleConnection()
                    .connectionUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/modeshape?autoReconnect=true")
                    .username("modeshape")
                    .password("modeshape")
                    .driverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").build();

        LocalEnvironment environment = new LocalEnvironment();
        environment.defineCache("myCache", cacheConfig); // Must match the cacheName property in your modeshape config

        String confPath = "<path to modeshape config>";
        RepositoryConfiguration repositoryConfiguration = RepositoryConfiguration.read(new File(confPath));
        repositoryConfiguration = repositoryConfiguration.with(environment);

        ModeShapeEngine engine = new ModeShapeEngine();
        engine.start();
        repository = engine.deploy(repositoryConfiguration);
```

Although, it is rather slow.

Comment: Have you tried adding "cacheConfiguration" field (at the same level as "cacheName") with a value that is the resource path of the Infinispan XML configuration? You can even use variables in the ModeShape configuration if you need to. See our the ModeShape documentation for details: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODE/ModeShape+in+Java+applications#ModeShapeinJavaapplications-ModeShaperepositoryconfigurationfiles

Comment: Thanks Randall. I raised this ticket for the problem i hit https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-3065